# Is there a detailed manual for php ARTISAN?

Tags: php, database, laravel

The most popular result from Google is from Laravel:

http://laravel.com/docs/artisan/commands#application-configuration

It should very very limited information. I can't find what data type it can support for the `Schema::table`... Can I create a `float` or `int` or `unsigned int`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this page http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema for Laravel 3

Docs for Laravel 4 http://four.laravel.com/docs/schema